# How to configure emacs tabbing behavior

Tags: emacs, tabs, ruby-mode

I've wrestled quite a bit with emacs tabbing, but haven't been able to figure this one out.

In ruby-mode:

```
SomeClass.create(
  this_is: where_i_want_to_tab,
  because: that_is_how_we_do_it
)

SomeClass.create(
                 this_is: where_emacs_wants_to_put_it,
                 but: my_pull_request_aint_gonna_be_merged_like_this
)
```

This is maybe a code style decision that the ruby-mode designers made, but is it possible to configure it?

Comment: Here are two related threads on tabs with ruby-mode:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925053/indent-with-tab-instead-of-spaces-in-emacs-ruby-mode  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111041/change-emacs-ruby-mode-indent-to-4-spaces

Comment: @lawlist They are related, but are separate issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can configure this in 24.3:

```
(setq ruby-deep-indent-paren nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior of `ruby-mode` cannot be configured, but it was changed in Emacs 24.4 (which will be released soon). There code like this:

```
SomeClass.create(
                 this_is: where_emacs_wants_to_put_it,
                 but: my_pull_request_aint_gonna_be_merged_like_this
)
```

will be indented like this:

```
SomeClass.create(
  this_is: where_i_want_to_tab,
  because: that_is_how_we_do_it
)
```

which is consistent with the existing [good practices](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout).

Comment: What do current ruby devs using emacs do? Hit the space bar? I mostly use Sublime Text, but I've been dabbling in emacs. This is the last pain point. Hopefully 24.4 is released soon :)

Comment: @harumph @h They probably use Emacs 24.4 pretest or Emacs trunk already.  It's easy to install on OS X and Ubuntu, and there are builds for Windows as well, iirc. On OS X, it's generally recommendable, since it includes a fair amount of OS X-specific improvements as well.